# Create an image template using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to create an image template using html5 canvas element, something like [this](https://picjoke.net/en/effect/7267-Photo+frame+with+actress+Yolanthe+Sneijder-Cabau+to+create+collage+and+photo+montage).

CSS has the 3d transform option, but that is only possible in the DOM and will not make any changes in the image. So i figured I should go with canvas.

My idea is : 
1) Create a canvas with a picture which has a transparent part.
2) Make another canvas on top of the first one, and position it on the transparent area with the .drawImage method.
3) Perspective transform the second image so it fits perfectly on the transparent area.

Now the first two are child steps, but the third one covers 3D manipulation, and I would need some ideas for that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it's tricky as you said.

Drawing multiple images in layers onto a canvas is not a problem and there's a way to set a 2D transformation matrix with `setTransform` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform))

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

var img = new Image()
img.src= 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/2-pt-sketchup.jpg'

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,512,341)

var img2 = new Image()
img2.src = 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=13&txt=230%C3%9750&w=70&h=80'

ctx.setTransform(1, Math.tan(Math.PI/-9), 0, 1, 0, 90);
ctx.drawImage(img2, 309, 135)
```

I'm not sure how to do a proper 3D transform with that one, but I'm sure there's somebody out there who does?

Comment: I hope there is, in the meantime I'll dig in some blog posts about 3d canvas transforms even though they seem exhausting to comprehend. Thanks.